# On a long proof

Tags: proof-writing, math-history

On wikipedia there is a claim that the [Abel–Ruffini theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) was nearly proved by Paolo Ruffini, and that his proof spanned over $500$ pages, is this really true? I don't really know much abstract algebra, and I know that the length of a paper will vary due to the size of the font, but what could possibly take $500$ pages to explain? Did he have to introduce a new subject part way through the paper or what? It also says Niels Henrik Abel published a proof that required just six pages, how can someone jump from $500$ pages to $6$?

Comment: This question is like poetry. I love it!

Comment: Sadly, only somebody with the stamina to slough through 500 pages of proof will be able to answer...

Comment: Perhaps Abel also invented CliffsNotes? ;)

Comment: As Ruffini never said (but should have), "I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this 500 page book is too narrow to contain."

Comment: The original proof of the [four color theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) involved a huge computer analysis that exceeds 500 pages.

Comment: I like this question, but I dislike the answers. Not that they're poorly written, but I feel they don't really address the main point of this question. I knew before about a lot of these long proofs (including Mochizuki's, classifcation of finite simple groups, Feit-Thompson) but I like this question because I really want to know about Ruffini's proof!

Comment: I never read a proof that's longer than two pages.

Comment: The relevant text in the wikipedia article is ambiguous to me: "While Cauchy felt that the assumption was minor, most historians believe that the proof was not complete until Abel proved this assumption. The theorem is thus generally credited to Niels Henrik Abel, who published a proof that required just six pages in 1824." Does the six page proof pertain to that assumption only?

Comment: I wrote a [blog post](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2008/06/paolo-ruffini.html) on Ruffini's life where I touch on what he accomplished and what he failed to accomplish.  My source on this is a wonderful book by Jean-Pierre Tignol.

Comment: The second volume of Ruffini's treatise is available from [books.google](http://books.google.no/books?id=XekSAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=paolo+ruffini+teoria+generale&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YxB1UcfnOMLXtQaQnIC4BQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=paolo%20ruffini%20teoria%20generale&f=false). My impression is that Ruffini tried to do a lot more than just prove the impossibility of solving the general 5th degree equation by extraction of roots. (For comparison, Abel's proof can be found [here](http://www.abelprisen.no/nedlastning/verker/oeuvres_1881_del1/oeuvres_completes_de_abel_nouv_ed_1_kap03_opt.pdf).)

Comment: @RossMillikan is there a shorter one, without computer analysis?

Comment: According to this http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmset.html#trivia it takes 25933 steps (~500 pages without comments at one step per line) to prove 2+2=4 in complex numbers if you start from axioms.

Comment: Maybe the title is misleading? The title seems to indicate that OP is interested in long proofs in general, whereas the question itself makes it clear that the answers should address the content of a very specific result (which none of them do).

Comment: @leo There is a shorter proof of 4CT by Robertson, Seymour and others.  It does rely on computer verification, but appears to be much simpler and is generally considered to be more trusted.

Answer (score 21):

Not only true, but not unique.  The [abc conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) has a recent (2012) proposed proof by Shinichi Mochizuki that spans over 500 pages, over 4 papers.  The record is the [classification of finite simple groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups) which consists of tens of thousands of pages, over hundreds of papers.  Very few people have read all of them, although the result is important and used frequently.

Comment: very few? no one!

Comment: Not so, see [this](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~motizuki/IUTeich%20Verification%20Report%202013-12.pdf) pdf, written by Mochizuki himself.  Five people are named, who each went through the entire work in great detail.

Comment: Coming from the future, was that abc conjecture proof eventually accepted?

Answer (score 16):

Math can be *very* difficult.

There are famous long proofs, like that of the Feit-Thompson theorem, whose initial proof took 255 pages of very intrincate arguments, or the classification of quasi-thin simple groups done by Aschbacher and Smith in 1221 pages, or well, the whole classification of simple finite groups —which is estimated in the tens of thousands of pages— of which the result of Aschbacher and Smith is a very small part.